# Navigation from Angular to JSP page

Tags: angular, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn angular and I have one scenario where I want to redirect from angular to jsp page : I tried the code provided below but it is not working.

Any help on this that how I can navigate from angular to jsp ?

```
viewdetails(value: string): void {
    this.buttonclick = value;
    this.Service.getDetails(this.pk, this.buttonclick, this.windowId).subscribe(
    //  error => alert('Failed to post  Main Icon header'),
    );
    this.router.navigateByUrl( '/list.jsp' );
}
```

Comment: you can use window.location if you don't have any guards

Comment: I tried with window.location but its not working , multiple redirect is happening

Comment: its not working because......?

Comment: Unless you different base href path I doubt it will happen. I am sure your server is having a url rewrite somewhere for the angular application to work. Put a different base  href path for angular in a subfolder and the route to a different jsp url may be in a different while putting a complete path using http and chck if that works. Alternatively, if you dont want to do that remove the url rewrite option from the server and enable hashLocationStrategy in your angular application. That might work.